# oracle DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE not running jobs

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have created below code, create_job is working fine but dbms_scheduler.enable is not running jobs automatically, however If I manually run created job i.e. begin REQUEST_PKG.CREATE_REQUEST('1234'); end; it runs successfully. Can someone please help me out here, to me it seems some compatibility/parameter passing issue in dbms_scheduler.enable.

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job
               (job_name        => job_name,
                job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
                job_action      =>    'begin REQUEST_PKG.CREATE_REQUEST('||seq_no|| '); end; ',
                enabled         => FALSE,
                auto_drop       => FALSE,
                comments        => seq_no
               );
DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE(job_name);
```

I am using oracle version 11.2.0.4.0.

Comment: Have you checked for any information in user_scheduler_job_run_details?

Comment: Yes job_name is populating and status is 'SUCCEEDED' in user_scheduler_job_run_details but job is not executing.

Comment: The job has been executed. Maybe it did not do what you expected. How do you check for succesful run of the job.

Comment: I receive email when it gets completed, this issue is happening after db upgraded to oracle version 11.2.0.4.0.

Comment: So maybe the emails do not get send.

Answer (score 1):

Check your database initialization parameters. Specifically JOB_QUEUE_PROCESSES.

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/initparams108.htm) says :

> If the value of JOB_QUEUE_PROCESSES is set to 0, then DBMS_JOB jobs and Oracle Scheduler jobs will not run on the instance.